# how to limit the number of digit after the float with python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

In my program I have several calculations that produce float numbers as results.
I would like to know if there's a general declaration in Python 3 that allows to limit all the floats in the program to let's say 8 digits, systematically ?

Thank you for your help !

```
# Create initial balance for user 1 and user 2.
bal_user1 = 21.82233503
bal_user2 = 5.27438039
# Calculate percentage of capital for each user
percent_capi_user2 = 100 * bal_user2 / ( bal_user1 + bal_user2)
percent_capi_user1 = 100 - percent_capi_user2
print("User 1 as " + str(percent_capi_user1) + (" % of the capital"))
print("User 2 as " + str(percent_capi_user2) + (" % of the capital"))
```

The output is :

```
User 1 as 80.53498253110413 % of the capital
User 2 as 19.465017468895866 % of the capital
```

I would like for example : 80.53498253 instead of 80.53498253110413
And since I'm doing several calculations later on in the program, I was wondering if there was a general declaration to put once at the beginning of the code. In order to avoid casting the right number of digits each time...

Comment: *"limit all the float"* - you mean limits the number of digits that you print or the number of digits used in calculation?

Comment: Both actually. I only need 8 digits after the float : ie. 0.00169001

Comment: Why do you need only 8 digits? What do the values you are using represent?

Comment: Because all the entry values have 8 digits. The extra digits are produced by the calculations...
I want to keep the formatting of 8 digits all along the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, buddy, I think I have just what you are looking for!

What you are looking for is the `decimal` module and the included `Decimal` class. Now, I am not going to go into it, because I am not that knowledgeful in it, but what I can do is point you in the right direction. In short, read the documentation here ( https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html?highlight=decimal#module-decimal ), and look for `decimal.getcontext().prec`, which will allow you to, at least with `Decimal` objects, control their precision "globally".